# How to load image from photos using new PHPicker in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, phpicker

I want to select an image from photos using new `PHPickerViewController` and I want to open `PHPicker` directly when my controller is load.

---

Like this

[image: Like this]

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
         // TODO: - Here I want PhotoPicker
       }
    }
```

Comment: Did you look at the doc? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerviewcontroller?language=objc There is even a sample code https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/selecting_photos_and_videos_in_ios?language=objc Side note, when the `viewDidLoad()`, it might not be visible yet, so you can't open (ie present) the `PHPickerViewController` yet.

Answer (score 11):

### you can call this method `openPHPicker()` when ever you want to place your PHPicker.

1. You can use this code also. for opening new [PHPicker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerviewcontroller).
2. For More Knowledge about PHPicker in WWDC21 [PHPicker WWDC20 Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10652/) and [PHPicker WWDC21 Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10046/)
3. WWDC PHPicker Notes [PHPicker Notes](https://www.wwdcnotes.com/notes/wwdc20/10652/)

---

```
import Photos
import PhotosUI


// MARK: - PHPicker Configurations (PHPickerViewControllerDelegate)
extension ViewController: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
         picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: .none)
         results.forEach { result in
               result.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { reading, error in
               guard let image = reading as? UIImage, error == nil else { return }
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   self.profilePictureOutlet.image = image
                   // TODO: - Here you get UIImage
               }
               result.itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "public.image") { [weak self] url, _ in
                // TODO: - Here You Get The URL
               }
          }
       }
  }

   /// call this method for `PHPicker`
   func openPHPicker() {
       var phPickerConfig = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
       phPickerConfig.selectionLimit = 1
       phPickerConfig.filter = PHPickerFilter.any(of: [.images, .livePhotos])
       let phPickerVC = PHPickerViewController(configuration: phPickerConfig)
       phPickerVC.delegate = self
       present(phPickerVC, animated: true)
   }
}
```